# Identify houseplant with tall stem and long thin leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

I am wondering if anyone could possibly identify this houseplant.  I don't know much about it, as I received as a gift.  It's fairly slow growing and quite resilient.  Lack of water will cause leaf tips to brown, but it recovers very well.

Thanks for your help.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Dracaena marginata; does well in low light conditions, should be watered when the surface of the compost is just dry to the touch, and watered well. Any excess water left in the tray under the pot should be emptied after 30 minutes so it's not left sitting in water. Dry tips can also be caused  by hot, dry air.

Comment: Dry tips are also caused by using tap water...I stopped using tap water and even though the air in winter is severely dry, the tips stopped browning.